# Connecto to SQL Server hosted in remote desktop

Tags: sql-server, node.js, database, windows

I'm working on a webapp with nodejs that syncs data from an ERP sql server database with an e-commerce website. The trouble is that I don't know how to generate the connection between the nodejs app(web) and the sql server, 'cause the way to access to the ERP enviroment is through the remote desktop with the IP and windows user credentials. All the npm modules that I've been testing only allow me to connect without the request of the user and password of the windows server.
I hope someone can help me somehow.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your remote computer's firewall to allow remote connections SQL's server port. After that you are required to create a user other than root ( since root only works locally ) on your database so you can connect to that one.Then using the npm module 'mysql' you can connect to your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is this a secure way to do it? or is this the only option?

Comment: This is the way you connect anyways when you buy an sql server in the cloud. They give you the ip,port and the credentials

Comment: I'm on it. Thanks again.